# Paypal Website Payment Pro Merchant Configuration Error

Tags: paypal, opencart

I have a store, based on opencart, and to this day I have two types of payments configured, one is paypal express checkout and the other is paypal website payments pro, for both options I needed to enter info like api password, username and signature, info that is the same for both cases - and double checked - when someone buy something and pay with paypal express checkout it works wonderfully, but when they try to use paypal website payments pro it says that there's a configuration merchant error. Checked and double checked, nothing, re-create the credentials again, nothing, I don't know what else to do I was wondering if someone around had the same error and if there's a solution for this?

Thanks a lot!

Arturo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invalid Merchant Configuration means that DoDirectPayment is not enabled on your PayPal account, which means you don't have Payments Pro active.

It could also mean that Pro was approved, but you never agreed to the $30/mo payment.  That agreement would show up in your overview when you login to your PayPal account.

Another possibility is that you've been approved for "PayPal Payments Pro 2.0" which uses the PayFlow API instead of the DoDirectPayment API.  In that case, DDP would not be enabled on your account and would result in the error you're getting.

Have you been paying the $30/mo to PayPal for Pro?

Comment: Hey Andrew, that was the thing, I just signed in for payments pro and agreed on the $30 monthly thing, now I have to just wait and see what happens, thanks so much!